# Discord.py Priveleged Intents stopping on_message and commands from working

Tags: python, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import random
import typing
from discord import Status
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
from discord import Member
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from asyncio import sleep


intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True

print(discord.__version__)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents =intents)

...
...

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('hiii, We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Exploring the archives"))
bot.loop.create_task(status())

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == BOT_ID:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello Dad!')

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before,after):
    if before.status  != str(after) :
        print("{}, #{} has gone {} .".format(after.name,after.id,after.status))

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left a server.')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined a server.')
    await member.send('Private message')

@bot.command(pass_context=True) 
async def summon(ctx):
       await ctx.send ("I have been summoned by the mighty {}, ".format(ctx.message.author.mention) + " bearer of {}. What is your command?".format(ctx.message.author.id))
```

Hello. I was trying to build a discord Bot and I was mostly successful except from the fact that I couldn't get on_member_join & on_member_update to work (they didn't even seem to register a user entering or leaving the server so I concluded that I lacked some permissions). After a lot of searching I found [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents) in the discord.py documentation and after adding the intents bit at the beggining of my code the on_member_join, on_member_remove & on_member_update worked, but the on_message event and all the commands do not work (i added a print at the beginning of on_message and nothing happened).
After some debugging I found out that the code that stops the commands from responding seems to be `,intents = intents)` . However when this is removed, the on_member_join, on_member_remove & on_member_update (understandably) do not trigger.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that using `intents = discord.Intents()` has all intents set to `False`.

You can either use [`intents.messages = True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.messages) or [`intents.all()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.all).

Comment: It's `Intents.all()` and not `intents.all()`. The latter won't work as expected since its a classmethod.

Comment: It works fine since `intents` is the variable storing `discord.Intents()`.

Comment: My example did not work as expected using python 3.8. I needed to called its the other way, I noticed this because it is marked as a clasmethod in the source.

Comment: Are you using `Intents = discord.Intents()`  instead of `intents = discord.Intents()`?

Comment: No....I am familiar with Python. As I pointed out, your code is incorrect and does not work as expected. It might run and interpreted but according to Discord API, it won't work as expected with the bit fields. One of these days I might post a full answer to prove it.

Comment: @Kurieita I have this within my own bot code and it runs as expected. You are welcome to post an answer that shows why it doesn't work.